# Query List of Dictionary<string, object>, can't cast from object to original type

Tags: linq, lambda, runtime, expression-trees

I need help with creating linq query for data below:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> entityProps = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            entityProps.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>{
                {"prop1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"prop2","test"+i},
                {"prop3", i /0.5},
                {"prop4", i}
            });
        }

        string propName = "prop3"; // I can also get eny of prop 1-4
        int value = 65;            // here for prop2 I receive string e.g. "test3"
        entityProps.Where(p => p[propName] == value);
```

I get following error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

I want to dinamically cast every prop to its type, because in future I want to use Expression trees to build in runtime lambda query for operation I receive (operations can be equal, less, greater...).
If I build Expression tree I will still need to cast data to its original type?

Thanks!

Comment: I can use `entityProps.Where(p => p[propName].ToString() == value.ToString());` but this works only for equal operator. I want to use greater than, less than..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write a helper method that ensures the type of the value prior to executing the predicate. Something like:

```
    public static bool CompareToObject<TSource>(TSource left, object right, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (right is TSource)
            return predicate(left, (TSource)right);
        else
            return false;
    }
```

which can be called with:

```
entityProps.Where(p => CompareToObject(p[propName], value, (x, y) => x == y));
```

Comment: This works `entityProps.Where(p => CompareToObject(value, p[propName],  (x, y) => x == y));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting to `int?`:

```
entityProps.Where(p => p[propName] as int? == value);
```

Comment: I don't know type of property till runtime. I would need something like this: `entityProps.Where(p => (p[propName] as p[propName].GetType()) == value);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast all ValueType variable to object with operator: (object)

But, i think you are doing it wrong. I would use a POCO class instead of a Dictionary.

Comment: No, this is not good. Operations like compare don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here would be to use `dynamic`.  Just make sure that the comparisons that you would have to do would make sense.

```
var query = entityProps.Where(p => (dynamic)p[propName] == value);
```

Done.

Generating the expressions necessary to do this would not be a trivial thing to do.  I'm sure there are libraries out there to do this already, don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to, especially when you don't know how to make it yourself.

A more practical approach would be to use some reflection to do this to call the appropriate methods and go from there.

Comment: I get error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation :(

Comment: You've shown your code where `entityProps` is a List.  Is that really the case or is that something else.  As a List, it should work as I've said.